# How get string of current Url in protractor?

Tags: protractor

i want to write some condition for protractor autotest. 
Example:

```
if (currentUrl == comparedUrl) {// do first;}
else {// do second;}
```

For this one i tried to use code:

```
 var currentUrl = browser.getCurrentUrl().then( function( url ) {
            return url;
            });
    console.log("current url = " + currentUrl);
```

i get response:

```
current url = ManagedPromise::122 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"};
```

but next code  works well:

```
var currentUrl = browser.getCurrentUrl().then( function( url ) {
        console.log(url);
    });
```

I don't understand why, and that one isn't what i need. I need to get a string of the URL.

Comment: Update the question with the string you are expecting from your current url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Promises and `browser.getCurrentUrl()`

Please review how promises work. In the following example:

```
var currentUrl = browser.getCurrentUrl().then( function( url ) {
  return url;
});
console.log("current url = " + currentUrl);
```

`browser.getCurrentUrl()` and the following chained callback both have the same return type `Promise<string>`. This means that `currentUrl` does not have a value of string. You will either need to continue chaining your thenables or change this to async / await.

### Setting async / await

You'll need to add the `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` in your Protractor configuration. Then in your test you'll be able to await Promises.

```
it('should do something', async () => {
  const currentUrl = await browser.getCurrentUrl(); // promise is awaited, result is a string.
  console.log(`current url = ${currentUrl}`); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation, very useful info :)

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your Protractor testing!

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to compare the current url with comparedUrl then you can just use browser.getCurrentUrl();

```
var currentUrl = browser.getCurrentUrl();

if(currentUrl === comparedUrl) {
 //do first
} else {
 //do second
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use async await

```
(async()=>{
var url = await browser.getCurrentUrl();
console.log(url)
})()
```

await will force browser.getCurrentUrl() to return a promise. Using async await you can avoid then callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
    var urlText = '';
    var currentUrl = browser.getCurrentUrl()
         .then(function(text){
             urlText = text;
             if (urlText == comparedUrl) {
                 // do first;
             }
             else {
                 // do second;
             }
    });
```

Hope it helps.